# Delete all data in aws neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

I have an aws neptune cluster and which I inserted many ntriples and nquads data using sparql http api.

curl -X POST --data-binary 'update=INSERT DATA { http://test.com/s http://test.com/p http://test.com/o . }' http://your-neptune-endpoint:8182/sparql

**I would like to clean all the data I inserted(not the instance)**

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [SPARQL DROP ALL](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#drop) to delete all your data.

If you want a truly empty database (no data, no metrics in cloudwatch, no audit history etc), then I would highly recommend creating a new cluster up fresh. It takes only a few minutes.

Comment: Example: `awscurl -X POST --region "${region}" --service neptune-db  --access_key "${access_key}" --secret_key "${secret_key}" "https://${url}:${port}/sparql" -d 'DROP ALL' -H "Content-Type: application/sparql-update"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to want to remove only the data you inserted, one strategy is to use named graphs. When you insert the data, insert it into a named graph. When you delete, delete the graph.

To insert, one way is to use a call similar to the insert you gave. Except you insert into a named graph:

curl -X POST --data-binary 'update=INSERT DATA { GRAPH http://www.example.com/named/graph { http://test.com/s http://test.com/p http://test.com/o . } }' 
https://endpoint:8182/sparql

Alternative is to insert using Graph Store Protocol:

curl --request POST -H "Content-Type: text/turtle" 
--data-raw " http://test.com/s http://test.com/p http://test.com/o . " 
'https://endpoint:8182/sparql/gsp/?graph=http%3A//www.example.com/named/graph'

Another is to use the bulk loader, which has namedGraphUri option (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/load-api-reference-load.html).

Here is a delete that removes the named graph:

curl --request DELETE 'https://endpoint:8182/sparql/gsp/?graph=http%3A//www.example.com/named/graph'

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/sparql-graph-store-protocol.html for details on the Graph Store Protocol in Neptune.